# Do I dispose CancellationTokenSource when I'm using it for timeout only in this use case?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, cancellationtokensource

This is a request-response model for websocket messages where you can technically match request id to response id and return the response. In addition to that, there is timeout in case that message is never matched.

The question is do I need to dispose the `CancellationTokenSource`? If so, where?

```cs
var requestManager = new RequestManager();
var input = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Test { Message = "Hello World" });

var pending = requestManager.AddPendingRequest(x =>
{
    var text = x.Deserialize<Test>();
    return text?.Message == "Hello World";
}, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

await Task.Delay(4000);

var jsonElement = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(input);

if (requestManager.TryMatchRequest(jsonElement))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
}

public class Test
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

### Code

```cs
public class PendingRequest
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public PendingRequest(Func<JsonElement, bool> handler, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Handler = handler;
        Event = new AsyncResetEvent(false, false);
        Timeout = timeout;

        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
        _cts.Token.Register(Fail, false);
    }

    public Func<JsonElement, bool> Handler { get; }
    public JsonElement? Result { get; private set; }
    public bool Completed { get; private set; }
    public AsyncResetEvent Event { get; }
    public TimeSpan Timeout { get; }

    public bool CheckData(JsonElement data)
    {
        if (Handler(data))
        {
            Result = data;
            Completed = true;
            Event.Set();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Fail()
    {
        Completed = true;
        Event.Set();
    }
}

public class RequestManager
{
    private readonly IList<PendingRequest> _pendingRequests = new List<PendingRequest>();

    public PendingRequest AddPendingRequest(Func<JsonElement, bool> handler, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var pending = new PendingRequest(handler, timeout);

        lock (_pendingRequests)
        {
            _pendingRequests.Add(pending);
        }

        return pending;
    }

    public void FailAllPendingRequests()
    {
        lock (_pendingRequests)
        {
            foreach (var pendingRequest in _pendingRequests.ToList())
            {
                pendingRequest.Fail();
                _pendingRequests.Remove(pendingRequest);
            }
        }
    }

    public IList<PendingRequest> GetAllPendingRequests()
    {
        lock (_pendingRequests)
        {
            return _pendingRequests;
        }
    }

    public bool TryMatchRequest(JsonElement tokenData)
    {
        lock (_pendingRequests)
        {
            foreach (var request in _pendingRequests)
            {
                if (!request.CheckData(tokenData))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                _pendingRequests.Remove(request);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void RemoveTimedOutRequests()
    {
        PendingRequest[] requests;
        lock (_pendingRequests)
        {
            requests = _pendingRequests.ToArray();
        }

        foreach (var request in requests.Where(r => r.Completed))
        {
            lock (_pendingRequests)
            {
                _pendingRequests.Remove(request);
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
///     Async auto reset based on Stephen Toub`s implementation
///     https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-2-asyncautoresetevent/
/// </summary>
public sealed class AsyncResetEvent : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly Task<bool> Completed = Task.FromResult(true);
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> _waits = new();
    private readonly bool _reset;
    private bool _signaled;

    /// <summary>
    ///     New AsyncResetEvent
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="initialState"></param>
    /// <param name="reset"></param>
    public AsyncResetEvent(bool initialState = false, bool reset = true)
    {
        _signaled = initialState;
        _reset = reset;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Dispose
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _waits.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Wait for the AutoResetEvent to be set
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task<bool> WaitAsync(TimeSpan? timeout = null)
    {
        lock (_waits)
        {
            if (_signaled)
            {
                if (_reset)
                {
                    _signaled = false;
                }

                return Completed;
            }

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
            if (timeout != null)
            {
                var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout.Value);
                cancellationSource.Token.Register(() =>
                {
                    tcs.TrySetResult(false);
                }, false);
            }

            _waits.Enqueue(tcs);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Signal a waiter
    /// </summary>
    public void Set()
    {
        lock (_waits)
        {
            if (!_reset)
            {
                // Act as ManualResetEvent. Once set keep it signaled and signal everyone who is waiting
                _signaled = true;
                while (_waits.Count > 0)
                {
                    var toRelease = _waits.Dequeue();
                    toRelease.TrySetResult(true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Act as AutoResetEvent. When set signal 1 waiter
                if (_waits.Count > 0)
                {
                    var toRelease = _waits.Dequeue();
                    toRelease.TrySetResult(true);
                }
                else if (!_signaled)
                {
                    _signaled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to have dedcated `object` for lock. See [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock#guidelines)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, I've heard exactly opposite that `List` is just fine for locking.

Comment: `AsyncResetEvent` is also disposable. That means `PendingRequest` should be too, as it already has two members that need disposing. The obvious candidate for disposing `PendingRequest`s is `RequestManager`, since it's responsible for creating them and forgetting about them (and, in turn, that probably means *it* should be disposable, in case things need to be cleaned up without waiting for completion).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, what is the impact of it not being disposed? like the downsides

Comment: Actually, you are not currently even disposing anything -- your `Dispose` clears out the queue, but does not dispose the contained `CancellationTokenSource`s. You should do that, while clearing the queue is actually unnecessary. As to the impact: the whole reason `IDisposable` exists is to ensure cleanup of resources that should not wait for garbage collection. So the impact is that you'll leak resources (most likely in the form of unmanaged object handles, if the CTS allocates any, which will ultimately translate as an increase in kernel memory).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, yeah. I'm not sure what the correct way to dispose it is.

Comment: I believe @StephenCleary helped me a year ago for that request response model.